# Adding geojson to openlayer3

Tags: javascript, openlayers, geojson

I have problem adding geojson to my tiledWMS map. When I remove geojson function "tiledWMS" works. Here I added also my geojson file: 
http://www.speedyshare.com/vpapQ/test.geojson
Below I added my script:

https://jsfiddle.net/w25b66rv/1/#&togetherjs=V6IbjQ1Jn0

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>test</title>
<script src="http://openlayers.org/en/v3.7.0/build/ol.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/proj4js/2.3.12/proj4-src.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>

proj4.defs('EPSG:2180', "+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=19 +k=0.9993 +x_0=500000 +y_0=-5300000 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs");

function init()
{
    var p = ol.proj.get('EPSG:2180');

    var mapTiles = new ol.Map({
        target: 'map',
        renderer: 'canvas',
        layers: [
            new ol.layer.Tile({
                source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
                    url: 'http://mapy.geoportal.gov.pl/wss/service/img/guest/ORTO/MapServer/WMSServer',
                    params: {
                        'LAYERS': 'Raster',
                        'CRS': 'EPSG:2180',
                        'VERSION': '1.1.1'
                    }
                }),
                isBaseLayer: true,
                projection: p
            }),
             new ol.layer.Vector({
      title: 'added Layer',
      source: new ol.source.GeoJSON({
         projection : 'EPSG:2180',
         url: 'test.geojson'
      })
  })
        ],




        view: new ol.View({
            center: ol.proj.transform([19, 52], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:2180'),
            zoom: 6,
            projection: p
        })
    });
    }

</script>
</head>
<body onload="init()">
    <div id="map"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am beginner , please I need a advice.

Comment: Your data is not GeoJSON, but some kind of invalid GML. Also, I noticed that you are using an outdated version of OpenLayers. v3.14.0 is the latest. Once you have a valid GeoJSON, the code in this fiddle should work for you: http://jsfiddle.net/w25b66rv/3/.

Comment: Yes I see TileWMS  but still geojson is not availabe .

Comment: Did you generate a new, valid geojson file?

Comment: Yes , in valid projection . Here is file :http://www.speedyshare.com/jwPYd/test.geojson . I see only map, not geojson ;/

Comment: Proj4.js does not know about the SRS string you are using, so you have to set an alias after defining EPSG:2180: `proj4.defs('urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::2180', 'EPSG:2180');`

Comment: Where exacly should I put this ?

Comment: Maybe using wms will be easier? Do sb know how I can change it